# Tensorflow: Custom Layer/Gradient result in OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement a custom layer with a custom gradient following the canonical reference [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers) and [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient)

For some reason, my code is throwing the following error:

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not
> allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you
> are trying to use an unsupported feature

My MWE is below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import sys

print("Python version")
print (sys.version)
print("Version info.")
print (sys.version_info)
print("Tensorflow version")
print(tf.__version__)

class Linear(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )

    @tf.custom_gradient
    def call(self, inputs):
        def grad(dy, variables=None):
            return tf.matmul(inputs, dy)
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w), grad

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    Linear(1),
])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')

xs = tf.constant([[-1.0],  [0.0], [1.0], [2.0], [3.0], [4.0]], dtype=float) 
print(model(xs))

ys = tf.constant([[-3.0], [-1.0], [1.0], [3.0], [5.0], [7.0]], dtype=float) 

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10)
```

The output is:

```
Python version
3.9.10 (v3.9.10:f2f3f53782, Jan 13 2022, 17:02:14) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
Version info.
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=9, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Tensorflow version
2.7.0
2022-11-10 17:21:03.514995: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:151] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.02415443]
 [-0.        ]
 [-0.02415443]
 [-0.04830886]
 [-0.07246329]
 [-0.09661772]], shape=(6, 1), dtype=float32)
Epoch 1/10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question.py", line 41, in <module>
    model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10)  
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 1129, in autograph_handler
raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 816, in train_step
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 530, in minimize
    grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 583, in _compute_gradients
    grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py", line 464, in _get_gradients
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that @tf.custom_gradients needs to return two variables, the gradient of dx and gradient of variables, you are only returning the dx_ part but not the gradient of variables, I have fixed the issue try this...

```
clear_session()
class Linear(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):  # Create the state of the layer (weights)
        w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
        self.w = tf.Variable(
        initial_value=w_init(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                             dtype='float32'),trainable=True)
    
    @tf.custom_gradient
    def call(self, inputs):
        wx = tf.matmul(inputs, self.w)
        def grad_fn(dy, variables = None):
            return tf.matmul(inputs , dy, transpose_b=True) , variables
        return wx , grad_fn

model = Linear(1)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
```

```
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=10)
```

```
Epoch 1/10
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 509ms/step - loss: 17.1162
Epoch 2/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step - loss: 17.1014
Epoch 3/10
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step - loss: 17.0867
```